# SharePoint List Formatting - Choice Field Overflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a choice field in my SharePoint list. The choice field is basically a tag list. Now I wish to display the tags on a single line. Everything what doesn't fit in the box should just be hidden.

Nice-to-have; have a gradient (solid to transparent) to give a peek to users that there is a more. Or a counter of the number of tags.

When you hover with your mouse a small pop-up would be preferable which shows all the tags.

Now the question is, how to achieve such behavior?

[image]

The default JSON of a (multi) choice field is:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "flex-wrap": "wrap",
    "display": "flex"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "__INTERNAL__ in @currentField",
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "display": "flex",
        "border-radius": "16px",
        "height": "24px",
        "align-items": "center",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "margin": "4px 4px 4px 4px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "class": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "[$__INTERNAL__]",
                "Safety"
              ]
            },
            "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCornflowerBlue sp-css-color-CornflowerBlueFont",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    "[$__INTERNAL__]",
                    "Privacy"
                  ]
                },
                "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-css-color-MintGreenFont",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "==",
                      "operands": [
                        "[$__INTERNAL__]",
                        "Ethics"
                      ]
                    },
                    "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgGold sp-css-color-GoldFont",
                    {
                      "operator": ":",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "==",
                          "operands": [
                            "[$__INTERNAL__]",
                            "Health"
                          ]
                        },
                        "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCoral sp-css-color-CoralFont",
                        {
                          "operator": ":",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "==",
                              "operands": [
                                "[$__INTERNAL__]",
                                "Working Conditions"
                              ]
                            },
                            "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgDustRose sp-css-color-DustRoseFont",
                            "sp-field-borderAllRegular sp-field-borderAllSolid sp-css-borderColor-neutralSecondary"
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "txtContent": "[$__INTERNAL__]"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Change the `flex-wrap` style from `wrap` to `nowrap`. This will prevent the tags from wrapping onto the next line, to hide the overflow, you can add `"overflow": "hidden"` to the style of the parent `div`. For the gradient this requires custom CSS or JavaScript, which is not supported in SharePoint column formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this JSON column formatting for your choice column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "style": {
    "flex-wrap": "nowrap",
    "display": "flex"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "forEach": "__INTERNAL__ in @currentField",
      "elmType": "div",
      "style": {
        "box-sizing": "border-box",
        "padding": "4px 8px 5px 8px",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "text-overflow": "ellipsis",
        "display": "flex",
        "border-radius": "16px",
        "height": "24px",
        "align-items": "center",
        "white-space": "nowrap",
        "margin": "4px 4px 4px 4px"
      },
      "customCardProps": {
        "formatter": {
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "padding": "10px"
          },
          "txtContent": "=join(@currentField, '; ')"
        },
        "openOnEvent": "hover",
        "directionalHint": "bottomCenter",
        "isBeakVisible": true,
        "beakStyle": {
          "backgroundColor": "white"
        }
      },
      "attributes": {
        "class": {
          "operator": ":",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "==",
              "operands": [
                "[$__INTERNAL__]",
                "Safety"
              ]
            },
            "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCornflowerBlue sp-css-color-CornflowerBlueFont",
            {
              "operator": ":",
              "operands": [
                {
                  "operator": "==",
                  "operands": [
                    "[$__INTERNAL__]",
                    "Privacy"
                  ]
                },
                "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgMintGreen sp-css-color-MintGreenFont",
                {
                  "operator": ":",
                  "operands": [
                    {
                      "operator": "==",
                      "operands": [
                        "[$__INTERNAL__]",
                        "Ethics"
                      ]
                    },
                    "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgGold sp-css-color-GoldFont",
                    {
                      "operator": ":",
                      "operands": [
                        {
                          "operator": "==",
                          "operands": [
                            "[$__INTERNAL__]",
                            "Health"
                          ]
                        },
                        "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCoral sp-css-color-CoralFont",
                        {
                          "operator": ":",
                          "operands": [
                            {
                              "operator": "==",
                              "operands": [
                                "[$__INTERNAL__]",
                                "Working Conditions"
                              ]
                            },
                            "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgDustRose sp-css-color-DustRoseFont",
                            "sp-field-borderAllRegular sp-field-borderAllSolid sp-css-borderColor-neutralSecondary"
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "txtContent": "[$__INTERNAL__]"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**On hover**: Shows all the topics separated by semicolon for simplicity - you can add custom CSS for elements on the pop up as per your requirements:

[image]